# What is the meaning of moment?

Tags: integration

Could you please explain the following sentence:

"In order to use the Riemann–Stieltjes integral for polynomials, we assume that all the moments are finite"

What do we mean by moment?
and why it is assumed to be finite?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral: $\operatorname{E}[f(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm{d}g(x)$......

Comment: The **moments** of Riemann-Stielgjes integrator $g$ are the integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n\;dg(x)$.  If all these moments are finite, then so are all integrals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\;dg(x)$ with polynomial $p$.

Comment: I know how the formula of the moment, but I do not know what do we mean by "moment". What other words can explain it?